# Check remaining email quota of alias

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am using this code to validate the remaining daily email quota but for some reason I do not think it is providing the correct number, or maybe I don't have the correct code.

```
function emailQuota(){
    var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
    Logger.log("Remaining email quota: " + emailQuotaRemaining);
}
```

I have two email addresses set up under my Gmail account: "Account settings -> Send Mail as" for example:

> (1) test1@gmail.com - primary account
>   (2) testsup@gmail.com --- Used regularly when responding to email inquiries and it is a group email account.

I would like to use the code above to check the #2 email address. Is this possible? Or does the code pick up remaining daily email quota as a whole (doesn't matter which account you used)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Apps Script quotas are related to the effective user. In other words to check the remaining email quota of testsup@gmail.com you have to run the script using that account.

Related

- [Is the GmailApp API send limit the same as MailApp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45938944/1595451)