# GmailApp per email recipient quota or how can I test GmailApp code without sending an email to 50+ people?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, quota

Google's quota for recipients per email is unclear. It says 50 [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). It says 100, [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en).

My current code uses MailApp and indeed it seems to fail with over 50 bcc'd:

```js
function sendEmail(form) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var body = form.body;
  var bcc = form.bccfield;
  var cc = form.ccfield;
  var to = form.tofield;
  var subject = form.subject;
   var eHandle = ss.getSheetByName("Email Handling");
  var sig = eHandle.getRange(10, 2).getValue();
  var img = eHandle.getRange(11, 2).getValue();    
  var sigImage = '<img src ="' + img + '" >';
  
MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: to,
  cc: cc,
  bcc: bcc,
    subject: subject,
   
  htmlBody: body.replace(/\n/g, '<br>') + sig + sigImage});
  }
```

I am considering switching to using GmailApp per the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64201309/mailapp-bcc-message-details-not-showing-in-sent-folder/64201858#64201858).

Will that get me up to the 100? A user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938944/is-the-gmailapp-api-send-limit-the-same-as-mailapp) suggested maybe but it doesn't seem resolved.

I would test it myself but how can I do that without actually trying to send an email to more than 50 people?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since both of the previous answers are correct for your question I think bundling them into this community wiki is a good thing.

1. [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) & [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) are Apps Script services, that are different from the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest).
2. You can also use Gmail API from Apps Script by [enabling it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) by activating "Gmail" in the Advanced Services.
3. The quotas you mention each refer to a different service.
4. For testing without spamming (other than yourself) you can use aliases. For example if your email address is: `myname@gmail.com` then you can make alias addresses by adding a slug in the following way: `myname+{text}@gmail.com` where "{text}" is a placeholder.

Answer (score 4):

The MailApp and GmailApp services aren't the same as the Gmail API

If you want to use the Gmail API quota in Google Apps Script instead of using MailApp / GmailApp you should use the Gmail Advanced Service.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced

Answer (score 3):

> How can I [test] that without actually trying to send an email to more than 50 people?

You can use email aliases to send the 50 emails to yourself:
If your email address is, for example, `myname@gmail.com`, then any address of the form

`myname+{text}@gmail.com`

will automatically route to your own inbox.

So you can use your script to generate a list of aliases, such as:

`myname+1@gmail.com`, `myname+2@gmail.com`, ...

and test for any number of email addresses without spamming anyone (well, except yourself... you'll receive 50 copies of that email).